# Updating multiple rows in one column in a database

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a database with the data

[image]

i want to edit the column with lab_no and add another zero (0) after the 8 for all the records... how can i do that because the records are many.
Thank you

Comment: Please give an example what you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you want to add `0` after each `8` in column `lab_no`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that all the records begin with EPI8, then you can do this:

```
UPDATE [tablename] SET lab_no = REPLACE(lab_no, 'EPI8', 'EPI80');
```